# Comment(s) or Speculative Answer?

Tags: discussion, answering-advice

Given a question asking for the original source of a quotation. Some digging around the 'net has thrown up an *avenue for further exploration* but not an answer. What I've found (and their links) would probably take at least a couple of comments.

Should I:

1. Post what I've found as one or more comments, risking a *potential* "don't answer in comments" response (even though it's not [yet] an answer)?
2. Post what I've found as an answer, even though it isn't really. The details *might* lead to answer, but *might* lead down a blind-alley.
3. Don't post anything because I don't have a full answer. The problem is that *I* probably can't take the digging any deeper, but someone else might be able to.
4. Neither, as asking for the source of a quotation is off-topic (doesn't seem to be specifically allowed or disallowed; may depend on how wide the "*and Usage*" part of the site is taken).

Comment: I always take option 1 and cheerfully ignore any abjurations about what others would like me to put into comments or not.

Comment: 1 or 2. Don't hide your research.

Comment: 4 is not the case. Provenance of quotes was established as ontopic long ago. Also, they tend not to be closed.

Comment: @user3850720 That was the question. Unfortunately, as it turned out, what I found wasn't very significant: I added what I found as a comment to KarlG's answer. (When I asked this question, using ngram-viewer, I'd found a reference to the phrase in an anthology of "great works", the original work being André Maurois's biography of Disraeli. Unfortunately, Google Books only showed a 6-line snippet so I had no idea whether there was anything worthwhile in it or not. Between asking here and KarlG's answer, I came across the PDF I quoted and realised it was only a passing reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've come up with an answer, even a partial answer, it's better as an answer so it can be peer reviewed.

If it isn't really even a partial answer, but it would help the asker do more research, it's better as a comment.

Comment: Thanks. With a bit more digging, it turns out it was the latter so I've left a comment.